# Add fragment to NavigationDrawer Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I created a project on Android Studio with `NavigationDrawer Activity`. 
It contains navigation list.

I want to start a fragment activity when I click on a navigation list.
Like I click on `Import` from nav bar and this will open new layer.

My codes are

Activity Main

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

App Bar main

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.sudarshaana.navtest1.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content_main

Activity_main_drawer

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camara"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

And Java Code

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

How to do so? I am new on Fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call your fragment like this:

```
 if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.main_fragment, New YourPreDefindeFragment());
        ft.addToBackStack("tag_back");
        ft.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
```

and add this code under user `</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` in XML

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: I am trying.
should I remove `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />`?

Comment: I think yes you have to.

Comment: Instead of adding `<FrameLayout android: id="@+id/main_fragment" ... />`, you can use the `content_main` layout generated by Android Studio: you can give an id to its layout (i.e. c_main), then modify the code above with: `ft.replace(R.id.c_main, new YourFragment());`. So, you should not remove `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />`. It works for me

Answer (score 2):

You just create new Fragment class which extend Fragment and their respective XML file and call them in MainActivity 
eg.

```
if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
      fragment = new newFragment();
} else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

}

 if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    // set the toolbar title
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In android studio 3.5 and above, this comes by default.

[image: Navigation Drawer]

You will notice different fragment are generated by default. which shows when navigation items are clicked.

```
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send,R.id.nav_accounts)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

You can also add a listener to item click and add another event like open new activity.

```
  navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {

            int menuId = destination.getId();

            switch (menuId){
                case R.id.nav_gallery:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You tapped gallery",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    fab.hide();

                    break;
                    default:
                        fab.show();
                        break;
            }

        }
    });
```

You can check out this tutorial for more details.
[Navigation Drawer](https://youtu.be/BlxQFoAGNZY?sub_confirmation=1)